# Doctrine2 loaded entities summary?

Tags: php, doctrine

How to display a summary of entities loaded into memory by Doctrine 2 ? At least show entities name and count, plus to add memory used.

It could be something like this :

```
Entity/Comment 1250 200Mb
Entity/Post 20 5Mb
Entity/User 5 1Mb
....
```

My code produce some memory overflows, and I need to understand how memory is consumed to detach/clear the right entities.

Answer (score 0):

Count by Entity class, but not memory usage yet :

```
$unitOfWork = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$identityMap = $unitOfWork->getIdentityMap();

foreach($identityMap as $entityName => $entities)
{
    $count = count($entities);
    echo "$entityName $count\n";
}
```